# How can i make my MVC application insider capable

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a project and i want my ASP.Net  to be able to have same capabilities like windows insider. For example i want to give some of the users the new features and functionality to test same like share point allows to deploy new feature to some of the users. Is there any platform available that i can use or i will have to modify my application to have this capability?

E.g. the Sharepoint today has this capability that we can select some users and then provide them access to have new feature and version or outlook allows you to see new features but user has capability to turn it of.

Answer (score 0):

There is one strategy:

You can do something like request forwarding.

You can install another web application with new features.

Then when user comes to your site you can ask them whether they want to see old application / new application.

If they select new, then on server side, you can redirect user to new web setup.

Once you aware that most of the people are going to new web tier, you can then shutdown old servers.

Obviously there will be other factors, like

- is this only UI level change or you have some data store and that is
  also going to change.
- If it requires change in underlying database, then how are you going
  to make sure that new application gets data from old database

You will have to think through and decide strategy best applicable for your solution.

I know this does not provide direct solution to your question, but this should given enough information on your question so that you can get started with some approach.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use an Authorize Attribute on a new controller defined for the new feature and add users who you want to have access to a role.

For example you could put users A, B and C into the Role "CanUseNewFeature" and just put a conditional if on the view something like:

```
   @if(User.IsInRole("CanUseNewFeature")
<a href="yourlink" /> Check out new feature! </a>
```

and the controller

```
[Authorise(Roles ="CanUseNewFeature")]
public class NewFeatureController : Controller
```